# Is it possible to configure Hibernate to allow Multi use Values?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading, relation

i'd like to ask is the following shema is realizeable with Hibernate:

I have a Table called Dog and another one called Owner.

I can have one Owner for severeal dogs. On the Other side i can have severeal dogs for severeal User. It's a thing of perspective i think.

The goal would be to realize a hbm.xml Map which allow to get all owner from a dog and to get all dogs from severeal owner.

I need to programm a Function that support this. I hope u can follow my thoughts.

I even tried it and got a recursiv StackoverFlow because when i'm calling for a dog it will try to fill his owner. When the owner is called from a dog it try's to get all dog from the current owner and again again till my overflow.

If this is to complex i can make a cutomized Code.

Thanks, so far.

Comment: This is a many to many mapping..

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you help me in another scenario ? Its like the dog and owner one but with a link table between them both who has  a dog_id and a owner_id and link them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this example will help you
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

Comment: Can you help me in a other scenario that i posted in the comments ?

Comment: Can you give your tables structure and your entities?

Comment: user99560 - THe Problem is now solved i got the Problem that my mapping lost the schema definition. I dont have any clue why but when i set the table to schema.dog instead of dog in my mappign it works! Thank you very much for yoru answer. You saved my Day!